# Mule - wrap http parameters with a fixed soap request

Tags: http, soap, xpath, mule, mule-studio

What transformer should I use to extract parameters from an http message like  `http://localhost:8088/?id=xxx&type=yyyy` ans put the values of the `id` and the `type` parameters into a fixed  soap request like :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsd="http://wsdouane/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsd:find>
         <entity>
            <id>xxxx</id>
            <type>yyyy</type>
         </entity>
      </wsd:find>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Http output

```
Cannot bind to address "http://127.0.0.1:8088/" No component registered on that endpoint
```

File output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:findResponse xmlns:ns2="http://wsdouane/"/>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

in order to pass to a JAX-WS web service?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of retrieving query params and setting them in an object and then into a SOAP object, is not a single step process with a single transformer.

Step 1: You can use

```
 <http-request-to-parameter-map>
```

transformer to get the query params as a Map.

Step 2: Then use this map to create a object with the map vlaues.

Step 3: And then send the object to your JAX-WS client component.

More reference of the transformers and the http and servlet module references can be found at below links.

[HTTP Transport Reference.](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference)

[Servlet Transport Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Servlet+Transport+Reference)

Updated answer to use XSLT and proxy client.

```
    <flow name="SOAPWebService" >

    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8088/"   exchange-pattern="request-response">          
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <set-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['id']]" variableName="paramId"></set-variable>
    <set-variable value="#[message.inboundProperties['type']]" variableName="paramType"></set-variable>

    <component class="com.example.components.SampleComponent" ></component>

    <mule-xml:xslt-transformer
        maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
        xsl-file="C:\WorkSpace\MyProject\src\main\resources\xslt\PrepareRequestXML.xsl">
        <mule-xml:context-property key="paramId"
            value="#[flowVars['paramId']]" />
        <mule-xml:context-property key="paramType"
            value="#[flowVars['paramType']]" />
    </mule-xml:xslt-transformer>

    <cxf:proxy-client payload="body"
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="true">           
    </cxf:proxy-client>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8080/ClientsDB/douane" doc:name="HTTP">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>   

    <byte-array-to-string-transformer   doc:name="Byte Array to String" />      
    <file:outbound-endpoint ....... .. />
</flow>
```

Below is the correct XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns="http://wsdouane/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="paramType"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="paramId"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="*" >
        <xsl:element name="find" namespace="http://wsdouane/">
        <xsl:element name="entity">
         <xsl:element name="id">
           <xsl:value-of select="$paramType"/>
         </xsl:element>
         <xsl:element name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="$paramId"/>
         </xsl:element> 
       </xsl:element>        
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code for SampleComponent class is

```
package com.example.components;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class SampleComponent implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        String str = "<sample> </sample>";
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but it would be better if I avoid using a SOAP component , just insert the parameters into the soap request and pass the xml directly to the service, is there another alternative??

Comment: I've already tried something like above but it does not work , you can take a look at this thread , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581702/consume-a-web-service-method-with-multiple-args-in-mule-esb
thank you, appreciate your help

Comment: I guess till the transformer there is not issue. Issue is happening when the object is being marshalled to post the SOAP request. Did you try adding a JAXB context to your config. So that the object you created can be easily marchalled. Like <spring:bean id="myJaxb" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance"> <spring:constructor-arg value="org.example.person" /> </spring:bean>  .  The constructor-arg here is the package where the ObjectFactory class is available.

Comment: should I put it between the transformer and the soap component ??
and what the <spring:constructor-arg value="org.example.person" /> represent?

Comment: This should be delared a global component. So that it is available in you mule context. By the way did you try this with a direct xml approach and cxf proxy service. because it seems easy in this case instead of all this wsdl2java, jaxbcontext.

Comment: Updated answer.  Try if you get it.

Comment: Ok, but what should I put into PrepareRequestXML.xsl ?

Comment: This is the XSLT code to prepare your XML.        <wsd:find  xmlns:wsd="http://wsdouane/">
         <entity>
            <id>xxxx</id>
            <type>yyyy</type>
         </entity>
      </wsd:find>
SOAP envelope will be added by the cxf proxy client.

Comment: You can get the params in xslt using   <xsl:param name="paramId"></xsl:param>

Comment: Could you please verify if the xslt stylsheet that I've post above in the question is good ??
thank you

Comment: Updated the flow and the xslt. Please try now it should work.

Comment: Ok ,
but it did not gives me the correct reply, please see the output, I've posted it in the question above.
thank you.

Comment: Updated the xslt to give you a proper namespaced xml. I could see the request is generated properly before posting to the jax-ws service. If this doesn't give the desired response, please check with the service you are calling. From the client side the request looks good. And this should solve your problem you posted in your question.

Comment: Thank you , all is working now like a charm, the issu came from the http adress, if we use only localhost:8088/ the GET parameters are not passing, but when I use or example localhost:8088/esb/ it works perfectly and I get the correct response.
thank you again.