# Mule - choice component issue

Tags: http, mule, mule-studio

When I run my flow, I get the following error `

```
<org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader>
  <reader class="org.mule.module.cxf.support.StreamClosingInterceptor$1">
    <reader class="com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader">
      <mXml11>false</mXml11>
      <mInputBuffer>xmlns:ns2=&quot;http://wsdouane/&quot;&gt;&lt;return&gt;&lt;douanePK&gt;&lt;idConteneurId&gt;ctr1&lt;/idConteneurId&gt;&lt;idCritereId&gt;C11&lt;/idCritereId&gt;&lt;/douanePK&gt;&lt;valeurId&gt;oui&lt;/valeurId&gt;&lt;/return&gt;&lt;/ns2:findResponse&gt;&lt;/S:Body&gt;&lt;/S:Envelope&gt;&#x0;&#x0;.................
```

we can see the correct soap response starting from the `<mInputBuffer>`, is there a way to get only the soap response??

here is my flow

```
 <flow name="SOAPWebService" doc:name="SOAPWebService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8088/esb" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload.contains('C22')]">
            <set-variable variableName="paramCtr" value="#[message.inboundProperties['ctr']]" doc:name="conteneur"/>
            <set-variable variableName="paramC" value="#[message.inboundProperties['c']]" doc:name="critere"/>
            <component class="com.example.components.SampleComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer  maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\resources\PrepareRequestXMLPort.xsl" doc:name="XSLT">
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramCtr" value="#[flowVars['paramCtr']]" />
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramC"  value="#[flowVars['paramC']]" />
            </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/ClientsDB/port" doc:name="PortWS"/>
            <byte-array-to-string-transformer   doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-variable variableName="paramCtr" value="#[message.inboundProperties['ctr']]" doc:name="conteneur"/>
            <set-variable variableName="paramC" value="#[message.inboundProperties['c']]" doc:name="critere"/>
            <component class="com.example.components.SampleComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\resources\PrepareRequestXMLDouane.xsl" doc:name="XSLT">
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramCtr"  value="#[flowVars['paramCtr']]" />
                <mulexml:context-property key="paramC"  value="#[flowVars['paramC']]" />
            </mulexml:xslt-transformer>                
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="body" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/ClientsDB/douane" doc:name="DouaneWS"/>
            <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <xm:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\MuleStudio\SandBox\output" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml " responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Outgoing File"/>
</flow>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This expression `#[payload.contains('c22')]` can't work because the payload is an `InputStream`. Aren't you seeing stack traces in Mule's logs?

In any case, try adding `<object-to-string-transformer />` before the `choice` and see if it fixes the issue.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that you're using XStream (in `xm:object-to-xml-transformer`) to serialize the CXF response object (`org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader`) into XML. The CXF response should not be messed with and should be handled by the `cxf:proxy-client` in the response phase of the flow. The `xm:object-to-xml-transformer` and `file:outbound-endpoint` after the `choice` router are probably disturbing this mechanism. Try to wrap them in a `response` element above the `choice` router to they execute after it in the response phase.

*Note that I have already given you this advice in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615537/387927 but you did not react to it.*

Also I don't think `byte-array-to-string-transformer` does anything: the message payload after the `http:outbound-endpoint`s should be `org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader`, preventing this transformer to fire.

Comment: I've tested the choice and now it's working fine thank you.
I've also updated the flow in my question.
Now I have another output, could you please help?
thank you

Comment: It's bad SO practice to modify an existing question once part of the issue has been resolved. I'll expand my answer to answer but in the future please open a new question.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I'm aware of it now.
Thank you.